# How to get all parent table data where child is not null in golang gorm

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have two models one is Path and another one is Node, Path is parent and node is child, I want to get all the paths where each path has at least one single node inside it.

Here is my models in golang

```golang
type Path struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID          uuid.UUID `json:"id" gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key"`
    Name        string    `json:"name" gorm:"type:varchar(255)"`
    Description string    `json:"description" gorm:"type:varchar(255)"`
    UserID      uuid.UUID `json:"user_id" gorm:"type:uuid"`
    Owner       User      `json:"owner" gorm:"foreignKey:UserID"`
    Nodes       []Node    `gorm:"foreignKey:PathID"`
}

type Node struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID          uuid.UUID `json:"_id" gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key"`
    Name        string    `json:"name" gorm:"type:varchar(255)"`
    Description string    `json:"description" gorm:"type:varchar(255)"`
    Url         string    `json:"url" gorm:"required"`
    Nodetype    string    `json:"nodetype" gorm:"type:varchar(255)"`
    PathID      uuid.UUID `json:"path_id" gorm:"type:uuid"`
    Path        Path      `gorm:"foreignKey:PathID"`
}

func (path *Path) BeforeCreate(tx *gorm.DB) (err error) {
    // UUID version 4
    path.ID = uuid.New()
    return
}

func (node *Node) BeforeCreate(tx *gorm.DB) (err error) {
    // UUID version 4
    node.ID = uuid.New()
    return
}
```

I am using gorm and here is the query I have tried but it seems not working when I have another path with same name or same fields values

```golang
db.Debug().Preload("Owner").Preload("Nodes").
    Joins("INNER JOIN nodes ON nodes.path_id = paths.id").Distinct("paths.id", "path.name").Find(&paths).Error
```

Comment: The Distinct() second parameter is misspelled (should be paths.name). To have a subsection of the Nodes to be preloaded you can use a func as decribed [here](https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html#Preload-with-conditions). However, the join is not necessary in my opinion.

Comment: @ManasPaul what is the issue if you have multiple paths with same name or maybe same id